# How to get the iter when early stopping happen using Spark xgboost4j?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost

I'm using the XGBoostRegressor, setting two parameters `num_early_stopping_rounds` and `maximize_evaluation_metrics`. Is there any way I can get the num of iter when the early stopping happen?
As shown in the [source code of `XGBoost.java`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/4ae225a08d3ff75d8d3a9f59ca477680cad2579c/jvm-packages/xgboost4j/src/main/java/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/java/XGBoost.java#L199-L207):

```
if (earlyStoppingRounds > 0) {
  boolean onTrack = judgeIfTrainingOnTrack(params, earlyStoppingRounds, metrics, iter);
  if (!onTrack) {
    String reversedDirection = getReversedDirection(params);
    Rabit.trackerPrint(String.format(
            "early stopping after %d %s rounds", earlyStoppingRounds, reversedDirection));
    break;
  }
}
```

The `iter` here could be the best num of round for training the model, but I have no idea how to extract this variable.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It should be just `model.summary.trainObjectiveHistory.size` where `model` is `XGBoostRegressionModel`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But for my test, it actually returned the `num_round` I set in the param_map, not the true number of round stopped by the early stopping.

Comment: I am using the SNAPSHOT build (post version 1.1.0). I also get the number of rounds from model.getNumRound which is the same as I set in the param_map. Also, when I provide my test dataset as a eval_set, the training summary shows my rmse is 0. However, if I calculate by hand, it is not 0.

Comment: @y33xiang, numRound in XGBoost4j is equivalent to the number of trees, thus it makes sense you get the same as provided in the paramMap. I am not aware of a way of getting the early stop round.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the best number of rounds calculated through early stopping, it is now supported by XGBoost from version [1.5.0](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-in-jvm-packages).

You can get them through this code as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/7095):

```scala
val xgbClassificationModel = xgbClassifier.fit(train)
val bestScore = xgbClassificationModel.nativeBooster.getAttr("best_score") 
val bestIteration =  xgbClassificationModel.nativeBooster.getAttr("best_iteration")
```

Here `xgbClassifier` is the XGBoostClassifier object. `bestIteration` is the value of `iter` that you wanted through your question.
The above code is a little different from the [PR](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/7095) as it is consistent with the code of [XGBoost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/jvm-packages/xgboost4j/src/main/java/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/java/XGBoost.java#L264).